# Combining layout_weight and maxHeight

Tags: android

I'm quite new to Android programming and I'm stuck on an simple problem.

I have a basic homepage with some buttons and a logo. I use a `LinearLayout` and the `layout_weight` attribute to distribute all the components.

Here is my code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="iut.project.findmeapp.MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/activityMainAppLogoIv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/null_height"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_logo"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxHeight="@dimen/img_maxHeight"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/img_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activityMainMyEventsBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/null_height"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_margin_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_margin_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/my_events" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activityMainMyContactsBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/null_height"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_margin_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_margin_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/my_contacts" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activityMainLastNotifBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/null_height"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_margin_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_margin_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/last_notification" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activityMainCopyrightTv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/null_height"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/tw_margin"
        android:text="@string/copyright" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*(Note : `@dimen/null_height` is `0dp`)*

My problem is that I want the image to scale with the size of the screen, but I don't want it pixelated : I have set a maximum height of **200px**.

The following lines don't seem to work, because the image has no limit and totally ignores the `maxHeight` attribute.

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:maxHeight="@dimen/img_maxHeight"
```

Actually it looks like this (example image) :

[image: Homepage]

It works perfectly, but when I set `maxHeight` to `10px` for example, nothing changes.

How can I achieve this ? I highly prefer to use a `LinearLayout`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the value of this (`@dimen/button_default_height`)?

Comment: @MSGadag The value is `0dp`. (i've read that I need this value to make `layout_weigh` work). I'll edit my question.

Comment: for ur `imageview` ur giving height as `wrap content` make it as `0dp`..and for last textview too

Comment: @MSGadag What can I do ? `match_parent` logically doesn't work, and I don't have any problem with the last TextView as it scales with the size of the screen.

Comment: set to 0dp and post ur desired image too n try my ans

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Evripidis Drakos for pointing me in the right direction. Just need a check to only set the max height if it's actually required.

```
public class MaxHeightImageView extends ImageView {

public static final int MAX_HEIGHT_NOT_SET = -1;
public static final int INDEX_MAX_HEIGHT = 0;
private static final int[] STYLE_ATTRIBUTE_ARRAY = {
        android.R.attr.maxHeight,
};

private int myMaxHeight;

public MaxHeightImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null);
}

public MaxHeightImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public MaxHeightImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public MaxHeightImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr,
        int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int size = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    if(MAX_HEIGHT_NOT_SET != myMaxHeight && size > myMaxHeight) {
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(myMaxHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    if(context != null) {
        TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                STYLE_ATTRIBUTE_ARRAY);
        myMaxHeight = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(INDEX_MAX_HEIGHT, 0);
    } else {
        myMaxHeight = MAX_HEIGHT_NOT_SET;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I dont think that you can combine `layout_weight` with `maxHeight`.
You could try subclassing `ImageView` to override the `onMeasure` method like so:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(200, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if u want to set exact height for your image u should use weightSum property with weight

**edit:**

for fixed height  do not give `weight` for `imageview` just take parent layout for `imageview` then add weight for that linear layout(parent layout) and for `imageview` give height as wrap content and `maxHeight`. when u use `weight` with `height="0dp"` the content will capture the whole `height` so it will ignore `maxHeight`.

try this

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="5"
    tools:context="iut.project.findmeapp.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/activityMainAppLogoIv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/quantity_hint"
            android:maxHeight="200px"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activityMainMyEventsBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="my_events" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activityMainMyContactsBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="my_contacts" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activityMainLastNotifBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="last_notification" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activityMainCopyrightTv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="copyright" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: This is my bad, I have made a mistake in my question. In fact, I want the image to scale on all screens, until a maximum height of 200 **px**, not 200 **dp** (my question had no sense). So your code works but won't stop the image before it is pixelated. (see example here with a huge screen : http://puu.sh/hgWZT/fb6a1d2f19.png ). I edited my question.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question.

Comment: With the exact code in my first post and a `img_maxHeight` of **10px**, it gives that : http://puu.sh/hgXAa/4fbf9acfad.png.

So `maxHeight` is totally ignored, and that's I don't want to happen.